# Haproxy Too Many Redirects

Tags: redirect, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I want to route trafic outside of Turkey to another domain, I write acl into haproxy so in Turkey it works as planned but outside of Turkey traffic redirects but shows too many redirects. What I am missing in this configuration. My traffic comes from Cloudflare

```
acl acl_tr req.hdr(CF-IPCountry) eq "TR"
acl test_hname hdr(host) -m end lbtest.test.com
acl test_de hdr(host) -m end lbde.test.com
use_backend test_backends if acl_tr test_hname
redirect code 302 prefix https://lbde.test.com unless acl_tr
use_backend test_backends if test_de
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone outside of Turkey accesses your site, they might get redirected once to `https://lbde.test.com` from your redirect rule. Assuming this hostname points to the same HAProxy instance, it will run into the very same redirect rule again, resulting in the same redirect to be sent.

To resolve this, you might want to leverage the `test_de` ACL there to not perform the redirect if the user is already requesting the `lbde.test.com` host:

```
redirect code 302 prefix https://lbde.test.com unless acl_tr || test_de
```

Finally, please make sure that you understand the order of rule evaluation in HAProxy. Although you have written your `redirect` rule after your first `use_backend` rule, it will still be evaluated before any `use_backend` rules.